# Find and Delete Folder in Linux [non root user]

Tags: linux, putty

I would like to search within my `/home/user` for a specific folder name and delete it and all its contents. There is a posibility that we would find multiple occurences of the same folder across many folders within `/home/user`

How do I go about this:
Note: Using PuTTY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
find /home/user -type d -iname "searchdir" -exec rm -ir "{}" \;
```

The `find` will search `/home/user` for all directories containing `searchdir` and execute `rm -ir` for all of them. It will prompt you for every directory whether it should remove it or not (the `-i` after `rm` does that).

Oh...and you might want to add `-d 1` to `find` if it should only search in the upmost hierarchy level.

Answer (score 1):

The command to find the folder with certain name is :-

```
find -type d -name "YOUR_NAME" -print0 | xargs -r0 rm -rf
```

The above command can avoid argument list too long :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037618/how-much-should-i-worry-about-argument-list-too-long/7037640#7037640

Lastly, if you have non-root user access, you likely getting permission denied

Answer (score 0):

use the command "find", search for a tutorial on it. a very powerful tool you should know.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation on how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using

```
find /home/user -name 'dir_name' -type d
```

will bring all directories matching `dir_name`. So you can use xargs and delete it recursively.

```
find /home/user -name 'dir_name' -type d | xargs rm -r
```

But, before running above command, check if `find` command returns all results properly. If you allows me a tip: instead of using `rm -r`, use `mv` and move your files to another folder, so nothing will be lost if problems occurs.